# Help me identify this bug with red belly hanging around garden pots

Tags: identification, bugs

I have these bugs crawling around my vegetable pots - mostly pepper plants. I've never seen these before. I'm new to this area of central Texas and need help identifying them. I'd like to know what they are and if they're pests or beneficial for the garden.

[image: weird bugs]

Comment: Looks like the young of a harlequin bug, they eat plants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are Largus nymphs. You can see more about them here:

[Largus nymphs](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1161478/bgimage)

[Another photo showing the young red bugs](https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/335362743)